# CC and BCC in the approval process email notification

Tags: email, approval-process, cc

I have an approval process where I send an email every time the quote is sent for approve. I would like to add a CC and BCC to this email. Are there any ways to do this?
Delegated approver doesn't work for me.
Thanks

Comment: I have a question. May I know, the user(s) which available in Cc or Bcc is need to doing any actions for the approval requested Quote record? OR You're adding those users like they are just need to aware for the record submission?

Comment: @MohanRaj, these are other approvers in this approval process

Answer (score 0):

In `Salesforce` **approval process** We already have an option to add more number of approvers in same step of approval.

During `approval process` configuration you can reach **Step 3** as `Select Assigned Approver` page.

In that page you can get below,

- Choose option **Automatically Assign to approver(s)**
- Under the option you can get the option as **User** (in dropdown) and you can able to `add row` to add new row to select the more then 1 user.
- In that way you can able to mention the parallel approver/more then one approver for the specific approval step.
- After you can choose any below option to decide the record will get approval **when all approvers are approved (UNANIMOUS)** or **any one is approved (FIRST RESPONSE)** basis,

[image]

After you set the approval process like this, once the record submitted, the SFDC system will send the email with request details of the record with mentioned all approvers in **To** section of that email.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It doesn't work for me. I have three steps in my approval process, each for one person. Only one person can approve each step. And this person gets an email. Another step has to be approved by the second person. He also gets and email. The third is the same. But they don't have to approve not their steps. They just have to be in CC of approve email. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Then you can create only two steps, First step to be Approved by 1 user and scond step to be approved by two user(follow the above answer mention and select "Approve or reject based on the First Response". This way all of them gets notification and only two will be able to approve and third one gets the notification.